# jQuery autocomplete de multiplas palavras

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Usando o seguinte código javascript

```
$.getJSON("../JSON/TAGS.json", function(tags) {
var tagsArray = [];
    for(var i=0; i<tags.length; i++){
        tagsArray.push(tags[i].tag);
    }
function split( val ) {
  return val.split( / \s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
  return split( term ).pop();
}

$( "#tag" )
  // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
  .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  })
  .autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function( request, response ) {
      // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
      response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
        tagsArray, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
    },
    focus: function() {
      // prevent value inserted on focus
      return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      var terms = split( this.value );
      // remove the current input
      terms.pop();
      // add the selected item
      terms.push( ui.item.value );
      // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
      terms.push( "" );
      this.value = terms.join( " " );
      return false;
    }
  });
 });
```

Consigo fazer com que o funcione o auto complete para multiplas palavras e palavras fora do array mas toda vez que dou um espaço é exibida a lista de palavras disponiveis para seleção (400 palavras)

Comment: o `autocomplete` do jqueryUI não realiza multiseleção por padrão, mas você consegue adicionar esta funcionalidade através de um código personalizado. Demo do próprio jqueryUI: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

Comment: @Oeslei Irei verificar e já comento

Comment: @Oeslei Colei o codigo correspondente, porem aonde colocarei o array de alavras?

Comment: Substitua a variável `availableTags` no código pelo seu array, ou seja, a variável `tagsArray`.

Comment: @Oeslei realizei as modificações (inclusive modifiquei os caracteres de separação "," por " ") e esta funcionando com ressalcas 1º toda vez que dou um espaço é exibida toda a lista, 2º o JSON é carregado toda junto com a pagina ou somente quando clico no input pois o JSON tem uns 10KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um filtro na função que disponibiliza o source:

```
source: function( request, response ) {
  // verifica se a pesquisa não está vazia
  if ( extractLast( request.term ) ) {
     response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
        tagsArray, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
  }
}
```

---

Com relação ao seu comentário, para não carregar o json junto com a página, você poderia fazer desta forma:

- Deixe a variável `tagsArray` global sendo um array vazio, ou seja, declare ela no início do script, fora de qualquer método com o valor `[]`.
- O autocomplete você configura ao carregar a página da mesma forma como está, mas fora do `$.getJSON`.
- Quando o input receber foco, carregue o json para a variável `tagsArray`.

---

Seu script final deverá ficar assim:

```
var tagsArray = [];

function split( val ) {
  return val.split( / \s*/ );
}

function extractLast( term ) {
  return split( term ).pop();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#tag" )
    .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
      if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
  })
  .autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function( request, response ) {
      if ( extractLast( request.term ) ) {
        response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
          tagsArray, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
      }
    },
    focus: function() {
      return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      var terms = split( this.value );
      terms.pop();
      terms.push( ui.item.value );
      terms.push( "" );
      this.value = terms.join( " " );
      return false;
    }
  });

  // repare na utilização do método one fazendo
  // com que a função seja executada apenas uma vez
  $("#tag").one("focus", function() {
    $.getJSON("../JSON/TAGS.json", function(tags) {
      for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        tagsArray.push(tags[i].tag);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: modifiquei o tamanho da lista exibida para 10 resultados, mas tenho alguns questionamentos 1º o JSON é carregado toda junto com a pagina ou somente quando clico no input pois o JSON tem uns 10KB

Comment: Da forma que você está utilizando ele está sendo carregado junto com a página.

Comment: Como faria para ser como ajax?