# Como tornar uma lista HTML pesquisável

Tags: javascript, html

Estou querendo colocar uma busca na página, parecida com o <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> do navegador. Eu tenho uma lista de links e esta pesquisa somente apontaria para esta lista. Segue um print para melhor entendimento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa lista está no DOM ou tens a lista numa array? queres esconder as que não fazem match ou mudar a côr?

Comment: Essa lista esta em um html simples. Eu gostaria de fazer igual ao Ctrl+f do navegador, conforme vamos digitando as letras ele vai "colorindo" as palavras que fazer referencia com as letras digitadas.

Comment: Podes juntar o HTML que tens?

Comment: Peço até desculpas Sergio, mas não posso fazer isso devido ao sigilo das informações contidas na página, que interna da empresa.
Só precisava de um código que fizesse isso que o restante eu adapto aqui.
Abs,

Comment: Eu só queria a estrutura do HTML... mas ok vou fazer uma estrutura inventada para responder

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda pessoal, vou fazer os testes hoje e posto depois para vcs.

Comment: É pessoal valeu pelas dicas, que servirão com certeza para outras partes da busca. Porem ainda não consegui o que estou precisando, que é uma perquisa parecida com a busca dos browsers mesmo (ctrl+f3).
Caso conseguisam alguma coisa, ficarei muito agradecido.
Abs,

Comment: Se ainda não conseguiste o que querias é melhor não aceitares nenhuma resposta e explicar melhor o que está a faltar em cada resposta... ( minha resposta esteve aceite um tempo e agora é outra que está aceite...)

Comment: Desculpa Sergio, eu não sabia que ao clicar estava aceitando a resposta, pensei que fosse como se eu tivesse lido aquela mensagem, ou até mesmo votado nela.

Comment: E que parte é que ainda não funciona?

Comment: Sergio, faça por favor um teste. Pressione no seu navegador ctrl+f3 ou ctrl+g e em alguns é o f3. Vá digitando as letras e veja. É isso que eu gostaria de colocar, sem precisar que o usuário precione esta combinação de teclas, ou seja o comando ficaria inserido em uma caixinha.

Comment: Viste o meu jsFiddle? -> http://jsfiddle.net/otrnsqvy/1/ não é isso que procuras?

Comment: Algumas destas respostas lhe atenderam?

Answer (score 3):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

```js
function marcador(letras, el) {
    el.innerHTML = el.innerText;
    var rgxp = new RegExp(letras, 'g');
    var span = '<span class="marcador">' + letras + '</span>';
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(rgxp, span);
}

var input = document.getElementById('busca');
var texto = document.getElementById('texto');
var divs = texto.children;
input.onkeyup = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
        marcador(this.value, divs[i]);
    }
}
```

```css
.marcador {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Procurar:
    <input id="busca" type="text" />
</div>
<div id="texto">
    <div>- A língua das Mariposas</div>
    <div>- A última tempestade</div>
    <div>- Agonia e Êxtase</div>
    <div>- Arquitetura da destruição</div>
</div>
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/otrnsqvy/1/

### Explicação:

Criei uma função marcador que procura num dado elemento por uma palavra (conjunto de letras). Quando encontra envolve-as com um `<span>` com uma classe de CSS que muda a cor para vermelho. Repara que no inicio faço `el.innerHTML = el.innerText;`, isso é para limpar o texto de `<span>`s anteriores.

Juntei também `input.onkeyup = function () {`. Isso faz com que uma função seja corrida a cada vez que uma tecla é libertada. Nessa função percorro todos os elementos `div` filhos de `#texto` e chamo a função `marcador(this.value, divs[i]);`. O `this.value` dá o valor do input (as letras/palavra).

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma além das citadas que pode ajudar é fazer o uso do elemento `datalist` do `HTML5`.

Mais informações [**Datalist - MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)

Como você tem uma lista de filmes pré-definida e o elemento trabalha com base nisso você pode fazer dessa forma:

**OBS:** Conforme você digita o nome, ele exibe apenas os filmes com os termos digitados. Um conselho é você criar a busca com os mesmos termos da lista citados na sua imagem de exemplo.

```
.wrapper {  
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  font-family: "Tahoma", sans-serif;
}

.wrapper span {
  display: block;
  color: #CCC;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.search {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.search-input {
  border: 0;
}
```

```
    <div class="wrapper">
      <span>Pesquisa</span>

      <div class="search">
        <input class="search-input" list="movies" placeholder="Pesquisa..."><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </div>

      <datalist id="movies">
         <option value="A Era do Gelo">A Era do Gelo</option>
         <option value="O Lobo de Wall Street">O Lobo de Wall Street</option>
         <option value="12 Horas">12 Horas</option>
         <option value="12 Rounds">12 Rounds</option>
         <option value="A Dama de ferro">A Dama de ferro</option>
         <option value="2 Filhos de Francisco">2 Filhos de Francisco</option>
         <option value="Exterminador do Futuro">Exterminador do Futuro</option>
         <option value="21 Gramas">21 Gramas</option>
         <option value="1408">1408</option>
      </datalist>
    </div>
```

**JSBIN: [Datalist](http://jsbin.com/putizujaku/1/)**

**OBS:** Lembre-se de aplicar o mesmo valor do atributo `LIST` do input no `ID` do datalist.

Answer (score 1):

Se tiver os links em um JSON por exemplo ou conseguir importa-los do banco, você poderá utilizar o [`JQuery Autocomplete`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/):

```
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
});
```

Ainda é possível usar um *Autocomplete* de múltiplas palavras, veja este link onde é mostrado como utilizar o *Autocomplete* com múltiplas palavras: [Multiple Autocomplete](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45963/jquery-autocomplete-de-multiplas-palavras).

Comment: Ok @bigown farei o commit

Answer (score 1):

Eu quando preciso fazer isso uso o Datalist do HTML 5. Por exemplo eu pego as informações de uma tabela (ex: categorias) e faço um foreach dentro dele. Abaixo um exemplo normal só em HTML:
`<input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>`