# Há algum modo de formatar uma linha inteira ao encontrar palavra na página

Tags: javascript, algoritmo-de-busca, dom

A idéia é o seguinte.. quando chamo uma função que traz valores duma `string` inclusa no *script* quero que a(s) palavra(s) que comecem como exemplo:

- Cores & Neutro

Se **destaque** das demais, suponhamos algumas frases simples, como:

```
Cores do Arco-Íris

Cores sortidas

Diversas cores e sabores

Sem cor, apenas Neutro

Preto-e-Branco, neutro

Sabão neutro
```

Bom, estas linhas devem ficar em "*negrito*" ja que contém as palavras **Cores & Neutro**.

Tenho apostado minhas ficha nessa rotina:

```
var negrito = "cores";
var indexar = string.indexOf(negrito);
if (indexar != -1) {
    // se for diferente de -1 é que a palavra foi localizada então faça uma ação
    ..style.fontWeight='bold';
}
```

Comment: Isso vai depender de como esta separada esta sua linha no dom.

Comment: Porque você tem que saber onde é o limite da frase, se uma frase é limitada por uma tag p por exemplo, basta colocar esta propriedade na tag p, mas se a separação for por um \n você vai ter que separada esta frase, é isso que estou querendo dizer.

Comment: Mas as frases estão em uma tag **p** no html, ou em variáveis no script?

Comment: @Leandro No documento HTML sem a _tag_ `p`, ela vêm do script quando clico no botão. Ela não esta envolvida entre delimitadores `<p>..</p>` por isso que estou querendo investir no rotina acima, pois deve procurar a palavra depois de ser trazido a frente, ja na página. Daí aplicar a formatação.

Comment: Formatar só a palavra encontrada seria bem mais simples. A linha toda é complicado, a menos que exista alguma marca não visual de onde é o início e o fim de cada linha.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesta resposta aqui do site, acho que te serve como base: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48604

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma é incluir tudo em um `<span>` para ter uma referência e separar as linhas com `\n`, depois fazer um filtro e incluir as tags `<b></b>` no texto que contém as palavras desejadas (explicações no código).

```js
var negrito = document.querySelector("body span").textContent // pega o texto da span
.split('\n') // converte em array pela quebra de linha
.filter(function(v){ // descarta valores vazios
   return v;
})
.map(function(v){
   if(/cores|neutro/.test(v.toLowerCase())){ // verifica as duas palavras sem diferenciar maúsculo e minúsculo
      v = '<b>'+v+'</b>'; // concatena negrito
   }
   return v; // retorna o valor
})
.join('<br>'); // converte em string com quebra de linha

 document.querySelector("body span").innerHTML = negrito; // substitui o conteúdo da span
```

```html
<span>
   Cores do Arco-Íris
   Cores sortidas
   Diversas cores e sabores
   Sem cor, apenas Neutro
   nada aqui
   Preto-e-Branco, neutro
   Sabão neutro
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara fiz um exemplo aqui, só para te dar uma idéia, até pq não entendi muito bem onde estão os parágrafos que vc que fazer o match. Utilizei o método **includes()** para procurar a ocorrência no parágrafo e fiz um for para percorrer todos os parágrafos. Espero que pelo menos te de uma idéia.

```js
var pTag = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var i;

for(i=0; i<pTag.length; i++) {
  var p = pTag[i].textContent;
  var cores = p.includes("Cores");
  var neutro = p.includes("Neutro");

  if(cores || neutro) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].style.fontWeight = "bold";
  } else {
    document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].style.color = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Cores do Arco-Íris</p>
<p>Cores sortidas</p>
<p>Diversas cores e sabores</p>
<p>Sem cor, apenas Neutro</p>
<p>Preto-e-Branco, neutro</p>
<p>Sabão neutro</p>
```

Comment: Boas novas! Era quase isso mesmo, porém não há `p` apenas texto. Mas ja tá valendo.

Comment: Então troca `<p>` por `<span>`, qual é o problema? Alguma tag tem que ter esse bendito texto, senão como você vai selecioná-lo univocamente?